# How to make Resteasy 2.3.6 use Jackson 2.+

Tags: jackson, resteasy

IS there a way to make RestEasy use Jackson 2+ ? It seems that RestEasy Jackson provider uses Jackson 1.9.9 and it's still a case for ResetEasy 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It occured to be quite simple. There are Jackson JAXRS providers in Jackson 2 already.

- `jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider`
- `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`
- `jackson-jaxrs-smile-provider`

So on the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

It's also good to exclude `resteasy-jettison-provider` to make sure you have no conflicts fo JSON handling.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to use Jackson 2.x with RESTEasy 2.x because the integration of Jackson 1.x is fairly tight.

However, RESTEasy supports Jackson 2.x as of version 3.0-beta-5 - please see [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-801) for details or do a [repository search](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jackson2-provider) if you're using Maven.